# is there an escape character for envsubst?

Tags: bash, shell, envsubst

Is there a way to prevent `envsubst` from substituting a `$VARIABLE`? For example, I would expect something like:

```
export THIS=THAT
echo "dont substitute \\\$THIS" | envsubst
```

and have it return

```
dont substitute $THIS
```

but instead I get

```
dont substitute \THAT
```

is there any escape character for doing this?

Comment: the easiest way is just `${VARIABLE%%}`

Comment: @SławomirLenart that does not seem to work?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

```
export DOLLAR='$'

export THIS=THAT
echo '${DOLLAR}THIS' | envsubst
```

Or more clear:

```
export THIS=THAT
echo '${DOLLAR}THIS' | DOLLAR='$' envsubst
```

Comment: This article quotes to claim that `DOLLAR='$'` is the worse way: https://qiita.com/takyam/items/e92e5a6ca1548cbd58db This answer should not be accepted.

Comment: @mpyw: That page is in Japanese. Can you summarize its argument(s) against `DOLLAR='$'`, and indicate what it recommends instead?

Comment: When talking about the `DOLLAR='$'` solution, the linked article's author states: "I do not think that this method is good, but I'm satisfied because I could accomplish what I wanted to do at first."

However, later he quotes the man page for `envsubst` referencing the command line parameter "`SHELL-FORMAT`" in `envsubst [OPTION] [SHELL-FORMAT]`.

This limits the variables:

> "If a SHELL-FORMAT is given, only those environment variables that are referenced in SHELL-FORMAT are substituted; otherwise all environment variables references occurring in standard input are substituted."

Comment: @TrinitronX Look at the `--variables` option behaviour.  All `SHELL-FORMAT` gives you is a means to limit the set of variables that get substituted, not prevent a given instance of something from being substituted.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware ;-)    Great to mention `--variables` flag too +1!  The comment I posted was intended to translate, relay, and summarize the information from the blog post in Japanese, as well as the man page.  I left out the bit about `--variables` for brevity.

Comment: My situation is not amenable to enumerating the variables I want to substitute, so this ugly hack seems to be the best available choice and has my upvote.

Answer (score 95):

If you give `envsubst` a list of variables, it *only* substitutes those variables, ignoring other substitutions. I'm not exactly sure how it works, but something like the following seems to do what you want:

```
$ export THIS=THAT FOO=BAR
$ echo 'dont substitute $THIS but do substitute $FOO' | envsubst '$FOO'
dont substitute $THIS but do substitute BAR
```

Note that `$THIS` is left alone, but `$FOO` is replaced by `BAR`.

Comment: That works but it's global. So you can't produce the "expected" output for `'The expansion of \$FOO is $FOO'`; either both FOOs are substituted or neither is.

Comment: Hm, ok. I admit, I wasn't really thinking about what the use case for `envsubst` is.

Comment: No it doesn't do what the asker wanted. The above accepted answer is correct.

Comment: @reza.safiyat See @rici's comment; `envsubst` doesn't respect escaped dollar signs in the string.

Comment: For more info in this and a few examples of doing this with nginx https://github.com/docker-library/docs/issues/496

Answer (score 23):

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ echo \$SHELL
$SHELL
$ echo \$SHELL | envsubst 
/bin/bash
$ echo \$\${q}SHELL | envsubst 
$SHELL
```

So doing `$$` allows you to add a `$` character. Then just "substitute" non-existent variable (here I used `${q}` but can be something more meaningful like `${my_empty_variable}` and you'll end up with what you need.

Just as with the paragraph solution - you need something special - here... a non-existent variable, which I like a bit more than performing additional sed on templates.

Comment: This is the best answer by far. It works even if you don't have the ability to introduce a special `DOLLAR=$` environment variable, and it doesn't require the use of a separate program like `sed`. If you only have control of the template those other solutions are total non-starters.

Answer (score 21):

My workaround is as follows:

Original template:

```
$change_this
$dont_change_this
```

Editted template:

```
$change_this
§dont_change_this
```

Now you can process:

```
envsubst < $template | sed -e 's/§/$/g'
```

This relies on the character `§` not occurring anywhere else on your template. You can use any other character.

Answer (score 11):

In my case I wanted to only escape vars that aren't already defined. To do so run:

`envsubst "$(env | sed -e 's/=.*//' -e 's/^/\$/g')"`

Comment: As a note: to use this in place e.g `envsubst "$(env | sed -e 's/=.*//' -e 's/^/\$/g')" < source.txt.template > target.txt`

Answer (score 11):

If there's only one or two variables you don't want to expand, you can sort of whitelist them by temporarily setting them to their own name, like this:

```
$ echo 'one $two three $four' | four='$four' envsubst
one  three $four
```

Here, the `$four` variable gets replaced with `$four`, effectively leaving it unchanged.

Comment: That's a clever trick.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative that I use, as it saves installing the entire `gettext` package for just one program. I have this awk script, I call `envtmpl`, it will swap any environment variable that looks like `{{ENV-VAR}}` for the value of `ENV-VAR`

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
{ for (a in ENVIRON) gsub("{{" _ a _ "}}",ENVIRON[a]); print }
```

So

```
$ echo "My shell '{{SHELL}}' is cool" | envtmpl
My shell '/bin/bash' is cool
```

As you can see, if `{{` & `}}` aren't what you prefer, its really each to change and this script works fine with `busybox`'s `awk`.

It's not going to be the world's fastest solution, but it's really easy to implement and I mostly run it to prepare config files, so speed is pretty irrelevant.

WARNING: The only **major** difference between this and `envsubst` is that this will **NOT** alter variables where no value exists. That is `{{HAS-NO-VALUE}}` will be left exactly as that, where as `envsubst` will remove those (replace them with blank).

You can fix this by adding more code into the `awk`, if you want.

Comment: I've been asked about no-value items a few times, so I made a github repo!! https://github.com/james-stevens/envsub/blob/main/envsub <- this include a `gsub` to also remove the `{{XX}}` that have no value. The `gsub` works in GNU `awk`, but does nothing in Busybox `awk`

Comment: Careful, this does recursive substitution. Think about what will happen if a variable's *value* will have `{{NAME_OF_SOME_SECRET_VARIABLE}}`.

Comment: It depends on the relatively arbitrary order of the names in the `ENVIRON` list whether you will get a recursive replacement or not. The variable `NAME_OF_SOME_SECRET_VARIABLE` will have to come *after* the name that holds it as a value, to get recursively substituted. Personally, I only use this for inserting environment variables into config file templates when starting up containers, so I have full control over the names & values - meaning recursion is not an issue for me

Answer (score 1):

Another way to "escape" some environment variable substitution is to use default value assignment (or any other variable processing) as envsubst will not substitute these:

```
$ export two=2
$ echo 'one $two three ${four:-}' | envsubst
one 2 three ${four:-}
```

The fourth envvar is not substituted, while in its output the processing to use defaulkt value is still there. This does not matter though, as processing this line later on will still deliver nothing if the variable is not set and its value when set.

Comment: `:-` is a shell thing, so this only works if you are running `envsubst` on a shell script, which seems to me pretty unlikely. It won't work (for example) in an `nginx.conf`

Comment: Indeed, if you need to inject some variables in a shell script, you are better off prefixing it with some variable assignments. E.g.: `{ printf -- '%s=%q\n' "$name1" "$value1" "$name2" "$value2" ... ; cat script-template.sh ; } > script.sh`

Answer (score 0):

It is not pretty but the way I did it is

```
export DONT_CHANGE_THIS=\${DONT_CHANGE_THIS}
envsubst < some-template.yml > changed.yml
```

So it will try to replace ${var} with \${var} and as output, you will get ${var} printed as it is

Answer (score -1):

I used escape character for this

```
MYENVVAR="\${MYENVVAR}"
export MYENVVAR
envsubst #whatever you want
```

then reset it to what actually I want

```
MYENVVAR="my value"
export MYENVVAR
```

Answer (score -1):

I just connected parts of other answers to create one-liner that substitutes vars prefixed with $, but ignores $$:

`echo "\$TEST ; \$\$l" > TEST_FILE
cat TEST_FILE
# $TEST ; $$l
export TEST=1
cat TEST_FILE | sed -e 's/\$\$/§/g' | envsubst | sed -e 's/§/\$/g'
# 1 ; $l`

Answer (score -1):

Expanding on the answer from @aaron, the substitution technique works when using Nginx-defined variables -- like $remote_addr -- alongside environment variables.

In my case, I'm running Nginx from Docker.

My directory structure:

```
docker-hello-world
├── certs/ 
│   ├── ssl_certificate_file.crt  # SSL Certificate named in .env
│   └── ssl_key_file.key  # SSL Key named in .env
├── nginx/
│   ├── .dockerignore  
│   ├── Dockerfile  
│   └── nginx.conf  # Nginx proxy server configuration
├── hello-world/
│   ├── .dockerignore 
│   ├── entrypoint.sh
│   ├── hello_world.py
│   └── Dockerfile
├── docker-compose.yml
├── environment.yml  # define the modules to include in the Python virtual environment
└── .env  # Application-wide environment variables
```

From my nginx/Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest
RUN apt-get update && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && rm -rf /etc/nginx/user.conf.d/*
RUN touch /etc/nginx/nginx.conf; \
envsubst "$(env | sed -e 's/=.*//' -e 's/^/\$/g')" < /etc/nginx/templates/default.conf.template > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf;
```

Comment: how about a simple ignore of lowercase values by sed? `cat template | sed -r 's/\$([a-z_][a-z_0-9]*)/§\1/g' | envsubst | sed -r 's/§([a-z_][a-z_0-9]*)/$\1/g'`

Comment: @Davoodeh Maybe. I don't know enough to know if there's a possibility of having predefined variables that use a starting capital letter.

Comment: My comment shows one way to do that. Although, it is not a built in feature based on my research.