# What does "DOLLAR=$ "do?

Tags: linux, bash

I am sitting with a bash script that does this

```
DOLLAR=$ envsubst < "in.conf" > "out.conf"
```

where I see these `DOLLAR`'s in the `in.conf` file

```
proxy_set_header            Host ${DOLLAR}host;
```

in `out.conf` have it become

```
proxy_set_header            Host $host;
```

**Question**

`envsubst` does search and replace of environment variables, but what is the purpose of `DOLLAR=$`?

Comment: Related: [is there an escape character for envsubst?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24963705/1983854)

Comment: It is the same as the purpose of `A=foo`.  It assigns the string on the right hand side of the `=` to the variable named on the LHS.  That is, the variable `DOLLAR` gets assigned the string `$`.